# greek letters validation php string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate input (aA-zZ & αΑ-ωΩ) I've so far came up with this because of regex etc didn't exactly work against XSS & 2nd order SQL injection.

But the following it prints error because it treats greek characters the ("α") as 2 byte characters.

```
<?php

validate_string_chars("aaαα");

function validate_string_chars($string) {

    //$valid_chars = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    //$valid_chars = range('a', 'z');
    $english_low    = range('a', 'z');
    $english_cap    = range('A', 'Z');
    $greek_low      = array('α', 'β');
    $greek_cap      = array('Α', 'Β');
    $valid_chars    = array_merge($english_low, $english_cap, $greek_low, $greek_cap);

    $errors = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++ ) {
        $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
        if (!in_array($char, $valid_chars)) { $errors++; }
    }

    echo "\n\r".$errors."\n\r";
}
?>

// Results: 4 (2 errors for each "α")
```

That's a $char var_dump:

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "a"
string(1) "�"
string(1) "�"
string(1) "�"
string(1) "�"
```

Comment: Instead of `strlen`, use `mb_strlen($string, 'UTF8')`, and I guess you will also need `mb_substr`. Does it fix the problem on your end? What regex approach did you try? Please share if you are interested in a regex approach.

Comment: What do you actually need? A function that checks whether all characters in the string are included in "valid_chars" ?

Comment: No idea, but have a look at [this snippet](https://ideone.com/RQ9JjC). Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Out of curiosity... Are you trying to prevent SQL injection by removing random bits in user data? That problem has been solved for years. In 2015 you should just use prepared statements and forget about it.

Comment: You may get better answers if you take a step back and tell us from the top what problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `preg_match('/[^a-zαβ]/ui', $string)`...?!

Comment: mb_strlen & mb_substr solved the problem, thank you

Comment: Alvaro G. Vicario really? Has 2nd order injection been solved? Prepared statements don't prevent the 2nd order because it's not direct SQL query based.

Comment: 2nd order injection is solved by not stupidly concatenating arbitrary data into new queries or `eval`ing it. It's exactly the same as first order injection: you need to build your queries using techniques which ensure it's syntactically what you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) and [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) with the UTF8 encoding to properly count the number Unicode characters:

```
for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($string, 'UTF8'); $i++ ) {  // <--- HERE
    $char = mb_substr($string, $i, 1, 'UTF8');         //    AND HERE --->
    if (!in_array($char, $valid_chars)) { $errors++; }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/RQ9JjC)

Actually, you can also match Unicode graphemes with `preg_match_all('/\X/u', $str, $matches)` where [`\X` is a shorthand class for a Unicode grapheme](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme).

Comment: @Realist: Please let me know if you need any more clarifications.