# preg_match() function in PHP returns improper result

Tags: php, regex

```
$sRangeRegex = '/^(.{0,30})?$/';
$value='12345678901234567890123456789ä';
if (!preg_match($sRangeRegex, $value)) {
    alert('not match');
}
```

When i run this code it returns 'not match' alert message. But actually it shouldn't be.
Because actual length of value should be 30 (number of characters in the $value)
but it shows 31
These umlaut characters are creating problem while matching.
So i want solution to solve this problem and with regex only.
Thanks.

Comment: That regex pattern you use does not make any sense at all. What are those `**` meant to do _outside_ the delimiters? About the "umlaut issue": you need to tell your regex engine that it should work in utf mode by using the `u` flag as modifier.

Comment: I was just trying to make bold. but how to tell regex engine to work in utf mode. Can you post an example ?

Comment: for length check why not just use `strlen`??

Comment: If pattern and input is utf-8 you need to specify the `u` flag. You can also use `\X` instead of dot `.` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/iI1cL0/2) `/^\X{0,30}$/u` that matches any number of Unicode characters that form an extended Unicode sequence.

Comment: strlen() gives 31. and mb_strlen() gives 30

Comment: @KshitijYelpale use `mb_strlen` since you are dealing with `utf8` chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is already common knowledge here on SO that in order to work with Unicode strings the PHP regex engine should get a pattern with `/u` flag. It is a less well-known fact that in order to match a Unicode grapheme one needs to use `\X` shorthand class (PCRE-compliant).

So, to apply some length restriction on a Unicode string pattern, use `\X` instead of `.`:

```
$pattern = '/^\X{0,30}$/u';
```

Note that this regex will match strings that contain 0 to 30 Unicode graphemes. You do not need any `(...)?` optional patterns, since `0` in the limiting quantifier already does this job.

However, to check the real length of the Unicode string, you need to use `mb_strlen`. See [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646605/greek-letters-validation-php-string/32646817#32646817) for an example.

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/XihsEE):

```
$pattern = '/^.{0,30}$/u';
$value='12345678901234567890123456789Å';
if (!preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
    echo "not match\n";
}
else echo "match!\n";

$pattern = '/^\X{0,30}$/u';
$value='12345678901234567890123456789Å';
if (!preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
    echo 'not match';
}
else echo "match!";
```

Results:

```
not match (this is the regex with a dot)
match!    (the regex based on \X)
```

Comment: Always providing detailed answer as expected +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your regex engine that it should work in utf mode by using the `u` flag as modifier:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/^(.{0,30})?$/u';
$subject='12345678901234567890123456789ä';

if (!preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens)) {
    alert('not match');
}
var_dump($tokens);
```

*Note the trailing `u` inside the pattern definition.*

The output is:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(31) "12345678901234567890123456789ä"
  [1] =>
  string(31) "12345678901234567890123456789ä"
}
```